# Targeting 31+ SDK requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to run my app on an android 12 device. the app has a GPS functionality.

When I run my app, I get the usual allow GPS pop up on the phone but then as soon as I 'allow' it, the app crashes and I see this error in Android Studio:

```
2022-10-07 18:08:53.471 11854-11854/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 11854
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.marianhello.bgloc.service.LocationServiceImpl@936d3d2 with null: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.app: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```

edit:

even though the code is large, I share it as suggested in the comments.

```
package com.marianhello.bgloc.service;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Process;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

import com.marianhello.bgloc.Config;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.ConnectivityListener;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.sync.NotificationHelper;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.PluginException;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.PostLocationTask;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.ResourceResolver;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.data.BackgroundActivity;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.data.BackgroundLocation;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.data.ConfigurationDAO;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.data.DAOFactory;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.data.LocationDAO;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.data.LocationTransform;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.headless.AbstractTaskRunner;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.headless.ActivityTask;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.headless.LocationTask;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.headless.StationaryTask;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.headless.Task;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.headless.TaskRunner;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.headless.TaskRunnerFactory;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.provider.LocationProvider;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.provider.LocationProviderFactory;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.provider.ProviderDelegate;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.sync.AccountHelper;
import com.marianhello.bgloc.sync.SyncService;
import com.marianhello.logging.LoggerManager;
import com.marianhello.logging.UncaughtExceptionLogger;

import org.chromium.content.browser.ThreadUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;

import static com.marianhello.bgloc.service.LocationServiceIntentBuilder.containsCommand;
import static com.marianhello.bgloc.service.LocationServiceIntentBuilder.containsMessage;
import static com.marianhello.bgloc.service.LocationServiceIntentBuilder.getCommand;
import static com.marianhello.bgloc.service.LocationServiceIntentBuilder.getMessage;

public class LocationServiceImpl extends Service implements ProviderDelegate, LocationService {

    public static final String ACTION_BROADCAST = ".broadcast";


    public static final int MSG_ON_ERROR = 100;

    
    public static final int MSG_ON_LOCATION = 101;

    public static final int MSG_ON_STATIONARY = 102;


    public static final int MSG_ON_ACTIVITY = 103;

    public static final int MSG_ON_SERVICE_STARTED = 104;

    public static final int MSG_ON_SERVICE_STOPPED = 105;

    public static final int MSG_ON_ABORT_REQUESTED = 106;

    public static final int MSG_ON_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION = 107;

 
    private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    private ResourceResolver mResolver;
    private Config mConfig;
    private LocationProvider mProvider;
    private Account mSyncAccount;

    private org.slf4j.Logger logger;

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private HandlerThread mHandlerThread;
    private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
    private LocationDAO mLocationDAO;
    private PostLocationTask mPostLocationTask;
    private String mHeadlessTaskRunnerClass;
    private TaskRunner mHeadlessTaskRunner;

    private long mServiceId = -1;
    private static boolean sIsRunning = false;
    private boolean mIsInForeground = false;

    private static LocationTransform sLocationTransform;
    private static LocationProviderFactory sLocationProviderFactory;

    private class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }

    /**
     * When binding to the service, we return an interface to our messenger
     * for sending messages to the service.
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        logger.debug("Client binds to service");
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        logger.debug("Client rebinds to service");
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        // All clients have unbound with unbindService()
        logger.debug("All clients have been unbound from service");

        return true; // Ensures onRebind() is called when a client re-binds.
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        sIsRunning = false;

        UncaughtExceptionLogger.register(this);

        logger = LoggerManager.getLogger(LocationServiceImpl.class);
        logger.info("Creating LocationServiceImpl");

        mServiceId = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
        // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
        // main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
        // background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.
        if (mHandlerThread == null) {
            mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("LocationServiceImpl.Thread", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        }
        mHandlerThread.start();
        // An Android service handler is a handler running on a specific background thread.
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());

        mResolver = ResourceResolver.newInstance(this);

        mSyncAccount = AccountHelper.CreateSyncAccount(this, mResolver.getAccountName(),
                mResolver.getAccountType());

        String authority = mResolver.getAuthority();
        ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(mSyncAccount, authority, 1);
        ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(mSyncAccount, authority, true);

        mLocationDAO = DAOFactory.createLocationDAO(this);

        mPostLocationTask = new PostLocationTask(mLocationDAO,
                new PostLocationTask.PostLocationTaskListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRequestedAbortUpdates() {
                        handleRequestedAbortUpdates();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onHttpAuthorizationUpdates() {
                        handleHttpAuthorizationUpdates();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSyncRequested() {
                        SyncService.sync(mSyncAccount, mResolver.getAuthority(), false);
                    }
                }, new ConnectivityListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasConnectivity() {
                return isNetworkAvailable();
            }
        });

        registerReceiver(connectivityChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
        NotificationHelper.registerServiceChannel(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        logger.info("Destroying LocationServiceImpl");

        // workaround for issue #276
        if (mProvider != null) {
            mProvider.onDestroy();
        }

        if (mHandlerThread != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                mHandlerThread.quitSafely();
            } else {
                mHandlerThread.quit(); //sorry
            }
        }

        if (mPostLocationTask != null) {
            mPostLocationTask.shutdown();
        }


        unregisterReceiver(connectivityChangeReceiver);

        sIsRunning = false;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        logger.debug("Task has been removed");
        // workaround for issue #276
        Config config = getConfig();
        if (config.getStopOnTerminate()) {
            logger.info("Stopping self");
            stopSelf();
        } else {
            logger.info("Continue running in background");
        }
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent == null) {
            // when service was killed and restarted we will restart service
            start();
            return START_STICKY;
        }

        boolean containsCommand = containsCommand(intent);
        logger.debug(
                String.format("Service in [%s] state. cmdId: [%s]. startId: [%d]",
                        sIsRunning ? "STARTED" : "NOT STARTED",
                        containsCommand ? getCommand(intent).getId() : "N/A",
                        startId)
        );

        if (containsCommand) {
            LocationServiceIntentBuilder.Command cmd = getCommand(intent);
            processCommand(cmd.getId(), cmd.getArgument());
        } else {
            // Could be a BOOT-event, or the OS just randomly restarted the service...
            startForegroundService();
        }

        if (containsMessage(intent)) {
            processMessage(getMessage(intent));
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void processMessage(String message) {
        // currently we do not process any message
    }

    private void processCommand(int command, Object arg) {
        try {
            switch (command) {
                case CommandId.START:
                    start();
                    break;
                case CommandId.START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE:
                    startForegroundService();
                    break;
                case CommandId.STOP:
                    stop();
                    break;
                case CommandId.CONFIGURE:
                    configure((Config) arg);
                    break;
                case CommandId.STOP_FOREGROUND:
                    stopForeground();
                    break;
                case CommandId.START_FOREGROUND:
                    startForeground();
                    break;
                case CommandId.REGISTER_HEADLESS_TASK:
                    registerHeadlessTask((String) arg);
                    break;
                case CommandId.START_HEADLESS_TASK:
                    startHeadlessTask();
                    break;
                case CommandId.STOP_HEADLESS_TASK:
                    stopHeadlessTask();
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("processCommand: exception", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void start() {
        if (sIsRunning) {
            return;
        }

        if (mConfig == null) {
            logger.warn("Attempt to start unconfigured service. Will use stored or default.");
            mConfig = getConfig();
            // TODO: throw JSONException if config cannot be obtained from db
        }

        logger.debug("Will start service with: {}", mConfig.toString());

        mPostLocationTask.setConfig(mConfig);
        mPostLocationTask.clearQueue();

        LocationProviderFactory spf = sLocationProviderFactory != null
                ? sLocationProviderFactory : new LocationProviderFactory(this);
        mProvider = spf.getInstance(mConfig.getLocationProvider());
        mProvider.setDelegate(this);
        mProvider.onCreate();
        mProvider.onConfigure(mConfig);

        sIsRunning = true;
        ThreadUtils.runOnUiThreadBlocking(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mProvider.onStart();
                if (mConfig.getStartForeground()) {
                    startForeground();
                }
            }
        });

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("action", MSG_ON_SERVICE_STARTED);
        bundle.putLong("serviceId", mServiceId);
        broadcastMessage(bundle);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void startForegroundService() {
        start();
        startForeground();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (!sIsRunning) {
            return;
        }

        if (mProvider != null) {
            mProvider.onStop();
        }

        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();

        broadcastMessage(MSG_ON_SERVICE_STOPPED);
        sIsRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void startForeground() {
        if (sIsRunning && !mIsInForeground) {
            Config config = getConfig();
            Notification notification = new NotificationHelper.NotificationFactory(this).getNotification(
                    config.getNotificationTitle(),
                    config.getNotificationText(),
                    config.getLargeNotificationIcon(),
                    config.getSmallNotificationIcon(),
                    config.getNotificationIconColor());

            if (mProvider != null) {
                mProvider.onCommand(LocationProvider.CMD_SWITCH_MODE,
                        LocationProvider.FOREGROUND_MODE);
            }
            super.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
            mIsInForeground = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void stopForeground() {
        if (sIsRunning && mIsInForeground) {
            stopForeground(true);
            if (mProvider != null) {
                mProvider.onCommand(LocationProvider.CMD_SWITCH_MODE,
                        LocationProvider.BACKGROUND_MODE);
            }
            mIsInForeground = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void configure(Config config) {
        if (mConfig == null) {
            mConfig = config;
            return;
        }

        final Config currentConfig = mConfig;
        mConfig = config;

        mPostLocationTask.setConfig(mConfig);

        ThreadUtils.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (sIsRunning) {
                    if (currentConfig.getStartForeground() == true && mConfig.getStartForeground() == false) {
                        stopForeground(true);
                    }

                    if (mConfig.getStartForeground() == true) {
                        if (currentConfig.getStartForeground() == false) {
                            // was not running in foreground, so start in foreground
                            startForeground();
                        } else {
                            // was running in foreground, so just update existing notification
                            Notification notification = new NotificationHelper.NotificationFactory(LocationServiceImpl.this).getNotification(
                                    mConfig.getNotificationTitle(),
                                    mConfig.getNotificationText(),
                                    mConfig.getLargeNotificationIcon(),
                                    mConfig.getSmallNotificationIcon(),
                                    mConfig.getNotificationIconColor());

                            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (currentConfig.getLocationProvider() != mConfig.getLocationProvider()) {
                    boolean shouldStart = mProvider.isStarted();
                    mProvider.onDestroy();
                    LocationProviderFactory spf = new LocationProviderFactory(LocationServiceImpl.this);
                    mProvider = spf.getInstance(mConfig.getLocationProvider());
                    mProvider.setDelegate(LocationServiceImpl.this);
                    mProvider.onCreate();
                    mProvider.onConfigure(mConfig);
                    if (shouldStart) {
                        mProvider.onStart();
                    }
                } else {
                    mProvider.onConfigure(mConfig);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void registerHeadlessTask(String taskRunnerClass) {
        logger.debug("Registering headless task");
        mHeadlessTaskRunnerClass = taskRunnerClass;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void startHeadlessTask() {
        if (mHeadlessTaskRunnerClass != null) {
            TaskRunnerFactory trf = new TaskRunnerFactory();
            try {
                mHeadlessTaskRunner = trf.getTaskRunner(mHeadlessTaskRunnerClass);
                ((AbstractTaskRunner) mHeadlessTaskRunner).setContext(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Headless task start failed: {}", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void stopHeadlessTask() {
        mHeadlessTaskRunner = null;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void executeProviderCommand(final int command, final int arg1) {
        if (mProvider == null) {
            return;
        }

        ThreadUtils.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mProvider.onCommand(command, arg1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocation(BackgroundLocation location) {
        logger.debug("New location {}", location.toString());

        location = transformLocation(location);
        if (location == null) {
            logger.debug("Skipping location as requested by the locationTransform");
            return;
        }

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("action", MSG_ON_LOCATION);
        bundle.putParcelable("payload", location);
        broadcastMessage(bundle);

        runHeadlessTask(new LocationTask(location) {
            @Override
            public void onError(String errorMessage) {
                logger.error("Location task error: {}", errorMessage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResult(String value) {
                logger.debug("Location task result: {}", value);
            }
        });

        postLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStationary(BackgroundLocation location) {
        logger.debug("New stationary {}", location.toString());

        location = transformLocation(location);
        if (location == null) {
            logger.debug("Skipping location as requested by the locationTransform");
            return;
        }

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("action", MSG_ON_STATIONARY);
        bundle.putParcelable("payload", location);
        broadcastMessage(bundle);

        runHeadlessTask(new StationaryTask(location){
            @Override
            public void onError(String errorMessage) {
                logger.error("Stationary task error: {}", errorMessage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResult(String value) {
                logger.debug("Stationary task result: {}", value);
            }
        });

        postLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivity(BackgroundActivity activity) {
        logger.debug("New activity {}", activity.toString());

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("action", MSG_ON_ACTIVITY);
        bundle.putParcelable("payload", activity);
        broadcastMessage(bundle);

        runHeadlessTask(new ActivityTask(activity){
            @Override
            public void onError(String errorMessage) {
                logger.error("Activity task error: {}", errorMessage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResult(String value) {
                logger.debug("Activity task result: {}", value);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(PluginException error) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("action", MSG_ON_ERROR);
        bundle.putBundle("payload", error.toBundle());
        broadcastMessage(bundle);
    }

    private void broadcastMessage(int msgId) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("action", msgId);
        broadcastMessage(bundle);
    }

    private void broadcastMessage(Bundle bundle) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_BROADCAST);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public Intent registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
        return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, null, mServiceHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver) {
        try {
            super.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            // if was not registered ignore exception
        }
    }

    public Config getConfig() {
        Config config = mConfig;
        if (config == null) {
            ConfigurationDAO dao = DAOFactory.createConfigurationDAO(this);
            try {
                config = dao.retrieveConfiguration();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                logger.error("Config exception: {}", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (config == null) {
            config = Config.getDefault();
        }

        mConfig = config;
        return mConfig;
    }

    public static void setLocationProviderFactory(LocationProviderFactory factory) {
        sLocationProviderFactory = factory;
    }

    private void runHeadlessTask(Task task) {
        if (mHeadlessTaskRunner == null) {
            return;
        }

        logger.debug("Running headless task: {}", task);
        mHeadlessTaskRunner.runTask(task);
    }

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Since this service runs in the same process as its
     * clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public LocationServiceImpl getService() {
            return LocationServiceImpl.this;
        }
    }

    private BackgroundLocation transformLocation(BackgroundLocation location) {
        if (sLocationTransform != null) {
            return sLocationTransform.transformLocationBeforeCommit(this, location);
        }

        return location;
    }

    private void postLocation(BackgroundLocation location) {
        mPostLocationTask.add(location);
    }

    public void handleRequestedAbortUpdates() {
        broadcastMessage(MSG_ON_ABORT_REQUESTED);
    }

    public void handleHttpAuthorizationUpdates() {
        broadcastMessage(MSG_ON_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION);
    }

    /**
     * Broadcast receiver which detects connectivity change condition
     */
    private BroadcastReceiver connectivityChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            boolean hasConnectivity = isNetworkAvailable();
            mPostLocationTask.setHasConnectivity(hasConnectivity);
            logger.info("Network condition changed has connectivity: {}", hasConnectivity);
        }
    };

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

    public long getServiceId() {
        return mServiceId;
    }

    public boolean isBound() {
        LocationServiceInfo info = new LocationServiceInfoImpl(this);
        return info.isBound();
    }

    public static boolean isRunning() {
        return sIsRunning;
    }

    public static void setLocationTransform(@Nullable LocationTransform transform) {
        sLocationTransform = transform;
    }

    public static @Nullable LocationTransform getLocationTransform() {
        return sLocationTransform;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your exception says "Unable to start **service** com.marianhello.bgloc.service.LocationServiceImpl", but the code you've shared is for creating a PendingIntent for an activity, not a Service. Please include the code that creates a PendingIntent for `LocationServiceImpl`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, please see my last edit.

Comment: Well, you've included the code for `LocationServiceImpl`, but that's not the code I was asking for. I was asking for the code that creates a PendingIntent for `LocationServiceImpl` - there's not one `PendingIntent.getService` in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your `build.gradle(app)` dependencies.

```
dependencies {
  // For Java
  implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1' 

  // For Kotlin
  implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain in detail how adding these libraries will affect `com.marianhello.bgloc.service.LocationServiceImpl`.

Comment: @drago: Ian asked for you to show the code that **creates your `PendingIntent`** for `LocationServiceImpl`. That is not what your edit contains.

Comment: This seems to fix the crash in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Some of dependency targets 31+ but didn't updated their flag. If you are not using any pending intent with such flag, we need to add [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/getting-started) dependency in our `build.gradle`(app) and that's it.

```
// Kotlin + coroutines
val work_version = "2.7.1"
implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version")
```

[Google Mobile Ads SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rel-notes) also start managing their library after `20.4.0` release.

> This release and all previous versions require an explicit dependency
> on androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0 to fix a bug causing app crashes
> on Android S with the following stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem by adding:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.0')
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0")
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

for anyone still facing this issue, it was resolved in FirebaseUIVersion 8.0.2
See this thread https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1999