# How/where to specify mutability in Cordova Android App

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, android-12, android-13

**Scenario:**
I have a Cordova based android app which targets android SDK = 31.It uses a location tracking plugin. It runs perfectly on android 11 and lower mobiles. In case of android 13, it only crashes in scenarios when the location tracking starts.

[Logcat error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16zBa.jpg)

Here's the Bug report generated by android 13 mobile:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.marianhello.bgloc.LocationService@705152b with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com. myapp.com/com.marianhello.bgloc.LocationService (has extras) }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com. myapp.com: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4846)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:275)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2223)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8301)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:577)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com. myapp.com: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)

    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
    at com.marianhello.bgloc.ActivityRecognitionLocationProvider.onCreate(ActivityRecognitionLocationProvider.java:60)
    at com.marianhello.bgloc.LocationProviderFactory.getInstance(LocationProviderFactory.java:43)
    at com.marianhello.bgloc.LocationService.onStartCommand(LocationService.java:239)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4828)
    ... 9 more
```

I have tried different solutions available on this platform as well as on others too.

I'm facing similar issue like this user: [Targeting 31+ SDK requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73989985/targeting-31-sdk-requires-that-one-of-flag-immutable-or-flag-mutable-be-specifi)
but the answers on the above question didn't work for me:(

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions, are you sure none of them work?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70894168/targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-one-of-flag-immutable-or-flag
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72919110/how-to-solve-this-targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-one-of-flag
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75325123/crash-on-android-13-with-parse-sdk-targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832565/targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-one-of-flag-immutable-or-flag
https://github.com/OneSignal/react-native-

Comment: Not sure where to add ' PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE' in Cordova based app. The FCMServices.java file has PendingIntent similar to it, but there are more than 6 such PendingIntents there. Do I need to add 'PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT' with 'FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT', 'FLAG_ONE_SHOT', as well?